# How to get one specific variable from an ArrayList which built for containing many variables?

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters

I have a class named Country. There is 2 Strings named "name" and "code" in Country class.
I made a constructor that includes both of them.
In main, I build up a Country with name "germany" and for name parameter,I enter "Germany" and for code, I enter "GER".

I also made an ArrayList called countries that works with the type "Country" and I've added germany in it.
So the question is, how can I call name parameter in that ArrayList?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. For this type of question, it's better if you can add your code.

Comment: Provide code example, also give the expected output, because what you asked if very unclear

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` does not have a direct method to get the object by the value of its properties, however it allows to retrieve objects by index using method `get(int i)` or by iterating and comparing the value.

```java
Country germany = new Country("Germany", "GER");

List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
countries.add(germany);

// use index
for (int i = 0, n = countries.size(); i < n; i++) {
    if (countries.get(i).getName().equals("Germany")) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
}

// iterate by index
for (Country country : countries) {
    if (country.getName().equals("Germany")) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
}

// use Stream API filter
countries.stream()
    .filter(country -> country.getName().equals("Germany"))
    .forEach(country -> System.out.println("Found!"));
```

---

If you need to look up the counties by name directly, a map `Map<String, Country>` should be used instead:

```
Map<String, Country> countryDictionary = new HashMap<>();
countryDictionary.put("Germany", germany);

countryDictionary.get("Germany"); // returns appropriate country or null
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's  definately  a way to do it. However, rather than focusing on one country name and manually typing it  , I was looking for a method that would provide me  to find countries' names without typing the name of those countries. What If I decide to print to console every single country name from that ArrayList? It's basically like you're using mySQL but your database is an ArrayList..That was actually what I was looking for. Just curiosity..Again, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Not sure I quite understand this _to find countries' names without typing the name of those countries._  Do you mean you need to search country names by country code, or by some index?  Printing the list content may be done as simple as: `countries.forEach(System.out::println)` if method `toString()` is properly implemented in `Country`

Answer (score 2):

You have he class Country with the appropriate constructor to instantiate an complete instance of a Country object. What you want is an ArrayList (or List) of Country, for example,

```
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, to fill the ArrayList with instances of Country you can do:

```
countries.add(new Country("Germany", "GER"));
countries.add(new Country("Sweden", "SWE"));
countries.add(new Country("Canada", "CAN"));
countries.add(new Country("United States of America", "USA"));
```

To get the ISO3 code from a supplied country name you might do:

```
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
    countries.add(new Country("Germany", "GER"));
    countries.add(new Country("Sweden", "SWE"));
    countries.add(new Country("Canada", "CAN"));
    countries.add(new Country("United States", "USA"));
    
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
// Get country code from country name:
String country = "";
while(country.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Enter a Country name or 'n' for next example:");
    System.out.print("Country: --> " );
    country = input.nextLine().trim();
    if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        break;  // Break out of current while loop
    }
    if (!country.matches("(?i)[a-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Try again...\n");
    }
    else {
         for (Country cntry : countries) {
            String ctry = cntry.getName();
            if (ctry.equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
                System.out.println("Country Code for " + ctry + " is: --> " + cntry.getCode());
                System.out.println("The List contains: --> " + cntry.toString());
                break; // Break out of loop;
            }
        }
    }
    country = "";
    System.out.println();
}
    
System.out.println();
    
// Get Country Name from Country Code:
String code = "";
while(code.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Enter a Country Code or 'n' for next example:");
    System.out.print("Code: --> " );
    code = input.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        break; // Break out of current while loop
    }
    if (!code.matches("(?i)[a-z]{3}")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Try again...\n");
    }
    else {
        for (Country cntry : countries) {
            if (cntry.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                System.out.println("Country Name for " + code + " is: --> " + cntry.getName());
                System.out.println("The List contains: --> " + cntry.toString());
                break; // Break out of loop;
            }
        }
    }
    code = "";
    System.out.println();
}
    
// Print the whole list:
System.out.println("\n  The whole list:\n  ===============");
for (Country cntry : countries) {
    System.out.println(cntry.toString());
}
```

This of course assumes the **Country** class is something like this:

```
public class Country {
    
    private String name;
    private String code;
    
    
    public Country(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-15s %-5s", name, code);
    }
}
```

All in all however, I think it's just easier to utilize the **[java.util.Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)** class to get this information, for example:

```
public static String getISO3CountryCode(String countryName) {
    String countryCode = null;
    String[] isoCountries = java.util.Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String country : isoCountries) {
        java.util.Locale locale = new java.util.Locale("en", country);
        String iso3 = locale.getISO3Country();
        String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(countryName)) {
            countryCode = iso3;
        }
    }
    return countryCode;
}
```

A way you might use this method:

```
System.out.println(getISO3CountryCode("Australia"));
```

or

```
String code = getISO3CountryCode("Australia")
```

This would ultimately supply you with the ISO-Alpha3 code of `AUS`. If you want the ISO-Alpha2 code (`AU`) then you would change the method code line of:

```
String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
```

with:

```
String iso = locale.getCountry();
```

If you want a list of all country codes...well I think you know what to do.

Comment: Appreciate for the help! There is quite a few things I don't know yet but I will try my best to get there.Thank you a lot!